# Processing Spacing

Tags: processing, spacing

I'm trying to draw bears in processing, (Just simple circles), how can I get the bears equally spaced apart, and have the same space from the edge of the screen to the bears, on either side? As well as vertically.

I know this is vague, but I'm terrible at explaining things

Answer (score 1):

Because you does not provide any code or example I will just tell you how to place circle in the middle of sketch.

For simplicity imagine this set up:

```
void setup(){
  size(400, 400);
}
```

**1)** Very basic approach would be to hard code position of this circle into ellipse draw function.

```
ellipse(200, 200, 50, 50);
```

Where first two parameters are coordinates for circle center. Simple find out from size `400x400` that mid is on coord `200x200`. This is bad approach and you should avoid using it.

**2)** Better approach would be to calculate center coord using global variables `width` and `height`

```
ellipse(width/2, height/2, 50, 50);
```

**3)** When you are drawing or moving more complex objects it is preferred to use some function to draw this objects always with same fixed position in our example

```
void draw_circle(){
  ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

And just moving center of drawing using [transformations](http://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) so our `draw` function will looks like this

```
void draw(){
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  draw_circle();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Using this you could be able to draw bears equally spaced apart and from sides.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a grid of equally spaced circles. For that you just need to divide your space into a grid in the x and y directions. The simplest way to do this is to wrap the kind of thing Majlik showed inside a double loop to move from cell to cell in your 'virtual' grid. To see this more clearly, in the code below there is an extra little bit so that if you press the 'g' key (for grid) you'll see the grid cells, with a circle centered in each one. You can press any other key to make the grid go away.

You can see that each way gives the same result: inside draw() uncomment the one you want and comment out the other 2.

```
int nx = 4;   // number of circles horizontally
int ny = 5;   // number of circles vertically
int divx;
int divy;
int diameter = 40;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  // calculate width and hegith of each cell of the grid
  divx = width/nx;
  divy = height/ny;
}

// 3 ways to draw a regular grid of circles
void draw() {
  background(200);
  // show the cell layout if the g key was typed, otherwise don't
  if(key == 'g')
    drawGrid();

  // 1 way
  for(int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < ny; j++ ) {      
      ellipse(i * divx + divx/2, j * divy + divy/2, diameter, diameter);
    }
  }

  // another way
  // for(int i = divx/2; i < width; i += divx) {
  //   for(int j = divy/2; j < height; j += divy ) {      
  //     ellipse(i, j, diameter, diameter);
  //   }
  // }

  // yet another way
  // for(int i = divx/2; i < width; i += divx) {
  //   for(int j = divy/2; j < height; j += divy ) {
  //     pushMatrix();
  //     translate(i, j);
  //     ellipse(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
  //     popMatrix();
  //   }
  // }
}

void drawGrid() {
    // draw vertical lines
    for(int i = 1; i < nx; i++) {
      line(i * divx, 0, i * divx, height);
    }

    // draw horizontal lines
    for(int j = 1; j < ny; j++ ) {      
      line(0, j * divy, width, j * divy);
    }  
}
```